# EOF Exception after Websocket onOpen from IE 11

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, websocket, java-websocket

I'm using a javax websocket server with javascript.
Websocket connection happens with the all other browsers except for IE (tired with IE 11 and 10).
onOpen is called and connection happens, after that EOFException is thrown with empty error message. Below is the stacktrace of the error

```
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1250)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1190)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:72)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Basically, I'm not able to figure out if it's server side or client side issue. Is there a timeout that I need to introduce from the client or server? or is the connection getting closed immediately and I need to introduce a ping-pong frame for that? Please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for it.

Basically, we need to check the request and respond headers in the IE, the request and response headers weren't the same as they were in other browser.
I have using the "sec-webSocket-protocol" where the value for this header was creating spaces in other browsers and there were no such spaces in IE 11.
Hence returning the same header which I received solved the issue